# How to set Authorization Bearer for Google API on CURLRequest CI4?

Tags: google-api, codeigniter-4

I already got access_token and want to access Google API with the following code:

```
$client = \Config\Services::curlrequest();
$userAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";
$response = $client->request("GET", $userAPI, [
            "version" => 1.1,
            "http_errors" => false,
            "header" => [
                "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $body->access_token],
            "debug" => true
        ]
    );
```

but I got 400 bad requests. The log on PHP spark didn't say anything about authorization.

```
GET /oauth2/v2/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 300
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
* upload completely sent off: 300 out of 300 bytes
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Content-Length: 1555
< Date: Sat, 06 Feb 2021 05:48:10 GMT
<
* Closing connection 0
```

Did I miss something?

edit:
Typo on "header", it must be "headers". It successfully sends authorization bearer but the status code still 400 bad request.
New log:

```
> GET /oauth2/v2/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 300
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0AfH***********************

* upload completely sent off: 300 out of 300 bytes
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Content-Length: 1555
< Date: Sat, 06 Feb 2021 06:49:54 GMT
<
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Change `"header" => [` to `"headers" => [`

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you! even though it still gets a 400 bad request but the authorization bearer is sent and I can see it in the log.

Comment: Update your question with the new status. Normally you put the access token as a query parameter. `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=$body->access_token`

Comment: Note my code uses v1 instead of your example which uses v2.

Comment: Another item. You show the header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The request should be a `GET`. That header should not be there.

Comment: Note: I believe the only content-type supported by this api is json.

Comment: @JohnHanley You are right. Before I do the GET requests I did POST requests first to get the access token `$response = $client->request('POST', $this->token_url, $data)` . It seems that the first request set that content-type. After I temporarily disabled the first POST request and access the GET requests directly it works and shows expected JSON data.

Comment: Please post an answer with the solution once you have everything working.